# Identifying the button from Multiple DIV elements

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

how to identify the Button Element in follwing html code

```
<TABLE id=aotbl_fileDetailsfields border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%"><TBODY>
<TR class=rowalternate>
<TD width="12%"><LABEL id=aolbl_filePath>File Path</LABEL> <LABEL class=labelmandate>*</LABEL> </TD>
<TD width="2%"><LABEL class=labelcolan>:</LABEL> </TD>
<TD width="30%">
<DIV style="POSITION: relative"><INPUT style="FILTER: alpha(opacity:0); HEIGHT: 30px; -moz-opacity: 0; opacity: 0" onchange="document.getElementById('amtxt_filepath').value=this.value;" tabIndex=-1 name=uploadFile type=file> 
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: -1; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 2px; LEFT: 150px">
**<BUTTON class=formBtn tabIndex=-1 onclick="document.getElementById('uploadFile').click();">Browse...</BUTTON>** </DIV>
<DIV style="Z-INDEX: 1; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px"><INPUT id=amtxt_filePath title="" name=amtxt_filePath.value maxLength=75> </DIV></DIV></TD>
<TD width="12%"><LABEL id=aolbl_worksheetName>Worksheet Name</LABEL> <LABEL id=aolbl_worksheetName_mandatory></LABEL></TD>
<TD width="2%"><LABEL id=aolbl_worksheetName_colan></LABEL></TD>
<TD width="30%"><INPUT id=amtxt_worksheetName class=reqInfo name=amtxt_worksheetName.value maxLength=50> </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Comment: There is no Button Element ! !

Comment: what do you mean by `Idenfying`?

Answer (score 2):

`//button[text()='Browse...']` OR `class=formBtn`

Comment: What is the answer for? what was the question BTW

Comment: hmmm detect for what? He has onclick aleady attached there.

Comment: to click on that or any other selenium operation. He is not able to detect button as there are many div tag.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what's already said, using a CSS locator:

```
button.formBtn
```

Comment: CSS selector is better option to detect the button element.

Answer (score 0):

I use firebug in firefox and use the little square box that says (on mouseover) "click an element to inspect" and then right click on the highlighted html in firebug to get options such as "copy xpath" or "copy css path".